# Setting up access control in Hudson for Jenkins Plugin for JIRA

Tags: plugins, hudson, jira, jira-plugin

I am currently testing [Jenkins Plugin for JIRA](https://marvelution.atlassian.net/wiki/display/JJI/Documentation+Home) as an alternative to [Atlassians Bamboo](http://www.atlassian.com/software/bamboo/overview) Continuous Integration tool for projects that I am working with. After reading documentation and creating some test project I managed to "connect" my Jira instance and my Hudson instance together. This is what I wanted to achieve initially (sequence diagram):

[image: jira-hudson-svn-integration]

Main use case:

1. User creates an issue in JIRA (ex. TST-1)
2. User resolves it after making some changes to the code. (Resolution: Delegate issue to Hudson CI)
3. User commits changes to Subversion (Commit message must contain issue code: TST-1 and 'Autobuild' (optional))
4. Build is triggered inside Hudson environment if 'Autobuild' string is found in the commit message
5. Hudson updates its copy of the project
6. Hudson build the project
7. Hudson updates corresponding issues (TST-1) on JIRA and resolves them leaving comment: 'Resolved by Hudson'

---

**The actual problem:**

If I set access control in Hudson instance to 'Logged-in users can do anything', I can 'connect' my Jira instance with Hudson instance. (I mean that inside Jira in Jenkins Configuration i can see # of Last Builds) But in case if I use 'Matrix-based security' or 'Project-based Matrix Authorization Strategy' access control in Hudson, then I am not able to see # of Last Builds.

More of the problem in screenshots:

**'Matrix-based security' Access Control:**

[image: Hudson access control settings]

[image: Hudson build history]

[image: Jira # of builds]

**'Logged-in users can do anything' Access Control:**

[image: Jira # of builds]

---

I have tried to install [Role-based Authorization Strategy](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Role+Strategy+Plugin) plugin and made two groups: Admin and Anonymous (allowing everything for Admin user and nothing for anonymous), but the effect is the same - not able to see # of Last Builds in Jira instance

After every update in Hudson Security, i restart hudson and remove/add application links again from the beginning (just in case..)

Did anyone had similar problems while configuring this plugin? If so, how did you manage to resolve this issue?

---

**P.S.**

I do not want to use `Logged-in users can do anything` access control setting, because in this mode Anonymous users will be able to get a lot of sensitive information just by browsing through my Hudson instance

<s>While writing this question, I changed from version `1.1.2` to `1.0.1` because `v.1.0.1` seems to be working better for me.</s> Using version `1.1.4` [(versions list)](https://marvelution.atlassian.net/wiki/display/JJI/Release+Notes).

Registered issue on marvelution: https://marvelution.atlassian.net/browse/JJI-41

**UPDATE:**

### The new release `1.2.0` fixed this issue.

What caused the problem:

> [when the schedular was triggered the basic header was not added](https://marvelution.atlassian.net/browse/JJI-47?focusedCommentId=15340&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-15340)

Comment: Last version solved the problem with synchronization while using `Logged-in users can do anything` access control setting, but not for `Matrix-based security` or `Project-based Matrix Authorization Strategy` access control settings

Answer (score 0):

Found out that if I use this setting in Access Control:
[image: hudson access controls]

then I am able to get # of builds in Jira using the plugin using `Matrix-based security` access control.

From [documentation](http://www.eclipse.org/hudson/the-hudson-book/book-hudson.chunked/ch04.html):

> A typical minimal configuration would be to grant all rights to an
>   administrative user or group and only read access for Overall and Jobs
>   to anonymous users.